# SAP Cloud Platform: Is it possible to access the git repository in another subaccount?

Tags: git, deployment, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I think the question is pretty straight forward (atleast in SAP Cloud environments), so I'll try to explain as briefly as possible. We have a global SCP account with 4 subaccounts of different production stages (development, test, integration an production).

We use SAP Web IDE Full-Stack in 'dev' subaccount, where all the git repos of the HTML5 Applications are stored. Everything is fine there. Now, when we want to deploy, we need to do the rollout step-by-step meaning from dev --> test, from test --> intg and so on.

Let's say I developed a new feature in dev and deploy this as new version 1.1.1. In the git repo, a new Tag "1.1.1" is created:

[Tags of the git repository for different deployed versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH83X.png)

Also, in the HTML5 Cockpit, the different versions can be seen and individually activated:

[List of deployed Versions, that can be activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOFn3.png)

So this is all good. But now, I want to deploy this version to the next subaccount (so the next stage). There are a few ways that came to mind:

1) Deploy from Web IDE of dev to any other subaccount. This works just fine, but the problem is that if you want to deploy the same version 1.1.1, but e.g. one week later, the code most likely has changed so its not the same version anymore

2) Export the version deployed to the dev subaccount (.zip) and import that version to another subaccount with the same version number. This works, but you have to do quite a few steps manually (for many different apps to 3 subaccounts). Also this method is prone to error due to the manual procedure.

3) The method I am thinking and asking this question about: Can you somehow change the git remote path from subaccount e.g. 'test' to the same git repo that is in the subaccount e.g. 'dev'? Because I don't really need to develop in a separate git repo in the 'test' subaccount.

But for the deployment process, it would be so much more convenient to just have to klick the magic wand and activate the new version in 'test' subaccount using the git Tags that are created in the git of the 'dev' subaccount.

I hope I could describe the problem as clearly as possible. The TLDR is: "Can I change the git repo of an HTML5 application from subaccount A, using another git repo of the same application in subaccount B?".

Thanks in advance and kind regards,

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. This is just a git repository like any other (Github, Gitlab etc). Just clone the repo inside your test and prod WebIDE. Btw I would recommend you to move away from the integrated repository and get something more advanced like Github/Gitlab/Bitbucket for better Code reviewing and continuous integration.

If you set up your CI/CD correctly you just need to push the changes and you’re done. You could even go a bit more advanced with multiple branches. Master branch is automatically deployed to dev and test and the stable branch is deployed to prod. If you then merge your new features from master into the stable branch, these get automatically deployed to production.

Greetings, Sebastian